# PHP autoload.php not found

Tags: php, server, instagram-api

so this is my code:

```
<?php
echo 'hey1';
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo 'hey2';
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
echo 'hey3';
/////// CONFIG ///////
$username = 'NetsGets';
$password = 'NetsGetsWebsite';
$debug = true;
$truncatedDebug = false;
//////////////////////

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);

try {
    $ig->login($username, $password);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(0);
}

try {
    $feed = $ig->discover->getExploreFeed();

    // Let's begin by looking at a beautiful debug output of what's available in
    // the response! This is very helpful for figuring out what a response has!
    $feed->printJson();

    // Now let's look at what properties are supported on the $feed object. This
    // works on ANY object from our library and will show what functions and
    // properties are supported, as well as how to call the functions! :-)
    $feed->printPropertyDescriptions();

    // The getExploreFeed() has an "items" property, which we need. As we saw
    // above, we should get it via "getItems()". The property list above told us
    // that it will return an array of "Item" objects. Therefore it's an ARRAY!
    $items = $feed->getItems();

    // Let's get the media item from the first item of the explore-items array...!
    $firstItem = $items[0]->getMedia();

    // We can look at that item too, if we want to... Let's do it! Note that
    // when we list supported properties, it shows everything supported by an
    // "Item" object. But that DOESN'T mean that every property IS available!
    // That's why you should always check the JSON to be sure that data exists!
    $firstItem->printJson(); // Shows its actual JSON contents (available data).
    $firstItem->printPropertyDescriptions(); // List of supported properties.

    // Let's look specifically at its User object!
    $firstItem->getUser()->printJson();

    // Okay, so the username of the person who posted the media is easy... And
    // as you can see, you can even chain multiple function calls in a row here
    // to get to the data. However, be aware that sometimes Instagram responses
    // have NULL values, so chaining is sometimes risky. But not in this case,
    // since we know that "user" and its "username" are always available! :-)
    $firstItem_username = $firstItem->getUser()->getUsername();

    // Now let's get the "id" of the item too!
    $firstItem_mediaId = $firstItem->getId();

    // Finally, let's get the highest-quality image URL for the media item!
    $firstItem_imageUrl = $firstItem->getImageVersions2()->getCandidates()[0]->getUrl();

    // Output some statistics. Well done! :-)
    echo 'There are '.count($items)." items.\n";
    echo "The first item has media id: {$firstItem_mediaId}.\n";
    echo "The first item was uploaded by: {$firstItem_username}.\n";
    echo "The highest quality image URL is: {$firstItem_imageUrl}.\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
?>
```

After running this code, the only things that print are hey1 and hey2. Based on my own reasearch, I concluded that autoload.php is one of the necessery files for the composer to run, but it also seems to be the problem that stops the php from running. This code is from https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API. Pease help!

Comment: Does this file exist? Did you install it via composer? Have you tried tried turning on error reporting and display?

Comment: just was about to ask the same thing that @kerbholz did: did you actually at any point do a composer install or just downloaded the repo as a zip?

Comment: I have composer and how do I turn on error reporting

Comment: And I will install and get back to you guys

Comment: [error_reporting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and also take a look at [display_errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you don't have Composer, install it. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install composer -y
```

2) Run:

```
composer require mgp25/instagram-php
```

3) Type:

```
cd vendor
ls
```

The very first file you see listed should be autoload.php.